# returning a reference to another object by creating a another object (confusing)

Tags: php, object

I am made a class that is called `SQL_Connection`. The purpose of this class is to return a reference (`$con`) to the calling variable. Example: `$conRef = new SQL_Connection();` Where `$conRef` would now be a reference of `$con` and not an instance of `SQL_Connection()`, if this is possible of course.

The construct function at the end does `return $con;`, I presume this may be the issue :/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `new` implies that you know the *exact* type of the object you want to construct.  The pattern you want to use is a factory method, not a constructor.  For example:

```
class SQL_Connection
{
    public static function create()
    {
        $con = new Other_SQL_Connection();
        return $con;
    }
}
```

Then invoke `SQL_Connection::create()` elsewhere to obtain the object reference.

Comment: So essentially I cannot return the variable by just calling the class?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell You cannot "call a class." You can call a constructor, but not a class.

Comment: could you not just use the `__construct()` function, create a variable outside of it called `$db`, and return `$this->db = new mysqli();`? then instantiating of the class would return the DB?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy but from what I was able to understand from this, when you do `$var = new Class()`, `$var` cannot be something other than the instance?

Comment: @MichaelMitchell The return value of the `__construct()` function is ignored. In your example, `$var` will *always* be an object of type `Class`, if the constructor does not throw an exception.

Answer (score -1):

As I think constructor methods can't return anything